# Symfony2 console - use on its own

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I have a small project with the following structure:

```
 -- bin
    -- init.php
 -- app
    -- all app directories here
 -- tests
 -- temp
```

I have installed the symfony2 console bundle using composer:

```
{
    "require": {
        "symfony/console": "2.3.*"
    }
}
```

and it installs the bundle into the vendor directory.  I therefore end up with the following structure:

```
 -- bin
    -- init.php
 -- app
    -- all app directories here
 -- tests
 -- temp
 -- vendor
    -- composer
    -- symfony
    -- autoload.php
```

How do i structure things so that in bin/init.php this uses the symfony console.  Essentially I want to create a single custom command that can be called from bin/init.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good starting point is always the [documentation of the console component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html).

IgorW's [composer-yaml](https://github.com/igorw/composer-yaml/blob/master/bin/composer-yaml) can serve as an example for a single file console application.

Further you can find inspiration by having a look at composer's [bin/composer](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/bin/composer), [src/bootstrap.php](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/src/bootstrap.php), [src/Console/Application.php](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/src/Composer/Console/Application.php) and i.e. [src/Command/AboutCommand.php](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/src/Composer/Command/AboutCommand.php).

Just combine composer's `bin/composer` and `src/bootstrap.php` into your `bin/init.php` ...

... then set the PSR-0 autoloading / base namespace to the app folder in your `composer.json` ([composer's composer.json](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/composer.json#L40)) ...

.... create a `app/<vendor>/Command/WhateverCommand.php` ...

create `app/<vendor>/Console/Application.php` (extend `Symfony\Component\Console\Application`) ...

...then register the command with your application in your `bin/init.php`...

```
use <vendor>\Console\Application;
use <vendor>\Command\WhateverCommand;

$application = new Application();
$application->add(new WhateverCommand());
```

.. finally  `run()` the application.

```
$application->run();
```

If you only want to have a single-command application have a look at the documentation chapter - [Building a Single Command application](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/single_command_tool.html).